# How to hide specific image in media library section in Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

How is it possible to hide specific image name in media library in Admin back-end.

Suppose I have an image name `"user_avatar.jpg"`. So I would like to hide this particular image in media section , I have also used following hook for this but not helpful.

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'wpse_hide_cv_media_overlay_view' );
function wpse_hide_cv_media_overlay_view( $args ) {
    // Bail if this is not the admin area.
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Modify the query.
    $args['meta_query'] = [
        [
            'key'     => 'title here',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ]
    ];

    return $args;
}
```

Is there any other hook for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'wpse_hide_cv_media_overlay_view' );
function wpse_hide_cv_media_overlay_view( $args ) {
    // Bail if this is not the admin area.
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Modify the query.
    $args['meta_query'] = [
        [
            'key'     => '_wp_attached_file',
            'value'     => 'user_avatar.jpg',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ]
    ];

    return $args;
}
```